# How to create/manage a job queue

Tags: bash

I have a queue of thousands of shell jobs in an ordered list, and I need to run 4 jobs in parallel from the top down to avoid saturating the cpu. If I simply split the job list into 4 batch scripts, then the runtimes don't align and one of the scripts will finish well ahead of the others still have many jobs left to do. Im looking for a way to have all 4 batch jobs pull from the top of the queue the next available job.

Ive tried the bash at jobs, but it's not what im looking for

Comment: Try searching `[gnu-parallel]` in the search box... `parallel -j 4 < joblist.txt`

Comment: Try `xargs -P` or GNU Parallel.

Comment: Can you give me a more concrete example? Let's say that I have a set of jobs called j0.sh to j99.sh. How would I use 'xargs -P 4' to keep 4 jobs running until all 100 have completed? (also, each job should have it's own logfile for stdout and stderr, j0.log to j99.log)

Answer (score 3):

I still like to make such scripts myself :p Below a script that runs commands depending on how large the N is. Once a process exits, the entry is used to store another child pid.

**run_from_file.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

N=4  # Amount of jobs to run in parallel
T=0  # Counter for amount of jobs
Q=() # Job queue
FILE='jobs.txt'

# Clean Q array
function _clean {
        for ((i=0; i < ${N}; ++i)); do
                tst=/proc/${Q[$i]}
                if [ ! -d $tst ]; then
                        Q[$i]=0
                fi
        done
}

# Setup the Q
for ((i=0; i < $N; i++)); do
        Q[$i]=0
done

while read -r line; do
        echo $line
        $line &

        # Try to find an open sport (Q[i]=0)
        while true; do
                for ((i=0; i < ${N}; ++i)); do
                        if [ ${Q[$i]} -eq 0 ]; then
                                Q[$i]=$!
                                break 2
                        fi
                done
                # Clean the Q array if no free entry is found
                _clean
        done
        ((T++))
done < ${FILE}
wait
echo "Processed ($T/$(wc -l < jobs.txt)) jobs"
exit 0
```

**jobs.txt**

```
sleep 1s
sleep 1s
sleep 1s
sleep 1s
sleep 10s
sleep 5s
sleep 2s
sleep 2s
sleep 4s
sleep 3s
sleep 3s
sleep 3s
```

OLD: 

<strike>I like to create such things myself because it's scalable. For instance, it allows you to do something before `wait` is called or you could get and store the child process IDs in a text file.</strike>

**run_from_file.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

X=0 # Counter 
N=4 # Total amount of parallel processes
FILE='jobs.txt'
while read -r line; do 
        echo $line
        $line &

        # Raise counter
        ((X = ++X % N))
        if [ "$X" -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Waiting"
                wait # Wait on processes to finish
        fi
done < ${FILE}

exit 0
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea by it isn't really: if one process takes longer than its siblings, you'll have idle CPUs while it's finishing. gnu parallel is preferable because it keeps all *n* CPUs busy continuously until there are fewer than *n* jobs left to run.

Comment: Hmm.. Never thought about that. I usually have processes that do the same. I will add an additional code example.

Comment: My job runtimes are wildly different (some run in 2-3 seconds some take 10 hours), but I want to keep 4 of them running at all times until I run out of jobs.

Comment: Both scripts do just that, but I would suggest to take the first of the two. Otherwise use one command in the comments underneath your question.